# How to show the soft keyboard from android ported app to blackberry z10 devices?

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I had ported android app to blackberry 10 devices. For showing keyboard implicitly,i had used following code

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(MyEditTextName, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Above code is working in android but not working in Blackberry Z10 devices.How to show/hide soft keyboard in blackberry Z10 devices by android code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried calling `imm.showSoftInput(MyEditTextName, 0)`?

Comment: I had submitted this code for testing due to unavailability of Z10 device.Testers will reply after two weeks.After receiving that result, i will inform you.Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Unfortunately its not working in Z10 device. Mr.Nate Any other possibilities ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a Z10 either.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle keyboard worked finally. And thanks to Mr.Nate

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```